# What is the length of a sequence with occurrences of the same elements?

Tags: sequences-and-series

According to Wikipedia, the number of elements (possibly infinite) of **sequence** is called the length of the sequence. Unlike a set, the same elements can appear multiple times at different positions in a sequence, and unlike a set, the order does matter.

So what is the number of elements of sequence $(3,3)$? i.e., what is the length of sequence $(3,3)$? Is the length of this sequence $1$ or $2$?

Comment: The length is $2$ , since it is not considered whether elements are equal.

Comment: @Peter Sure. Yeah. It should be 2. But can we say sequence (3,3) has two elements? Or just one?

Comment: What about a constant infinite sequence $(3,3,3,\cdots)$ ? All elements are equal, but they can nevertheless be numbered : $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots$ , so in this case we have infinite elements. In your example, I would speak of two elements although they are equal.